# How to run a cell without copy source in console?

Tags: python, spyder

- When executing a script with the command "Execute(F5)", the source is not copied in the console ;
- When executing a cell with the command "Execute the cell (Ctrl-Return)", the source is copied in the console ; what I do not want.

I don't find the configuration option to prevent this behaviour. Is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This functionality will be available in our next major version (Spyder 4, to be released in 2019) through a command called `runcell`, which runs cells without copying its source to the console. Besides, this will be the default behavior from that version onwards.

Comment: No problem, glad you found it useful.